# I want segment the patches of size 32x32px or more using python's opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, image-segmentation

Here I have a image:
[image: **Image_Original.jpg**]
Then I have generated threshold image using the code below.

```
img = cv2.imread('Image_Original.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_gr = np.array([40,0,0])
upper_gr = np.array([90,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_gr,upper_gr)
mask=~mask
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = ~mask)
cv2.imshow('Masked',mask)
cv2.imshow('Result',res)
```

Then the following images (masked):
[image: **Masked**]
and (result):
[image: **Result**]

Now what I want is to remove the black pixels(**FROM THE ORiGINAL IMAGE ONLY**) by making them zero and I want to extract only patches of size 32x32px or more.

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do. remove black pixels by setting them to zero - will only leave them black (black is zero). what kind of 32x32 patches are you after? can you provide an example? are you trying to get crops around the "dots" segmented from the original leaf image?

Comment: You can see that there are brown patches in the image of different sizes, what I want is to extract them only to a newer image and make everything else 0

Comment: @ParasKumarLangyan So you want each of the brown patches to be resizes to pathces of size 32x32 is that it?

Comment: @JeruLuke what i want is only patches of size 32x32 or more. rest of them should be changed to black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cv2.findContours() to find the boundaries of the white patches in your mask image.
Each boundary is returned as a list of 2D points.

Use cv2.boundingRect() to get the width/height of each patch and filter accordingly.
You could also use cv2.minAreaRect(), or cv2.contourArea() to filter based on actual area of the patch.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.htm

Once you have determined which patches should be discarded, overwrite them with black on the colour image using cv2.fillPoly().